# Regex to extract temperatures and temperature ranges from a string

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Okay I have this string:

```
-64.5(Ethylene glycol monobutyl ether acetate)- -24.4 deg C(N-Methylpyrrolidone)
```

And the final result I am looking for is this:

```
-64.5 - -24.4 deg C
```

The inclusion of dashes in the chemical name and the negative numbers as well as the dash separator to indicate a temperature range is killing me!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Example inputs:

```
> 1000 °C ( > 1832 °F )
> -64,6 deg C (Ethylene glycol monobutyl ether acetate)
-30 to -15 deg C ( -22 to 5 deg F )
-64.5(Ethylene glycol monobutyl ether acetate)- -24.4 deg C(N-Methylpyrrolidone)
```

Expected Outputs:

```
two results: > 1000 deg C and > 1832 deg F
> -64.6 deg C
-31 - -15 deg C
-64.5 - -24.4 deg C
```

Sorry if I am not describing what I am trying to accomplish very well!

Comment: Can you give some other examples of inputs? From what you described `/([0-9.-]|deg C)/` would work, but I'm sure that's too specific.

Comment: Sure: **>1000 °C ( > 1832 °F )** or **> -64,6 deg C (Ethylene glycol monobutyl ether acetate)** or **-30 to -15 deg C ( -22 to 5 deg F )** What I am really looking for is the temperature data either by itself or as a range. So just deleting junk inside the parens won't work unless there is no number followed by deg C or deg F .... see simple! :)

Comment: Add examples to the question, not as a comment! It's also still not entirely clear what you're actually asking for?

Comment: Still not 100% clear, but there's an answer below that gets at least some of the way. Let me know if makes sense or needs expanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to do what you want, although so far it doesn't split/remove temperatures in parens, because it's not clear why example 1 should have two results whilst example 3 only has one result?  (Is it relevant that one is a range and the other not?)

It works by removing the bits you don't want, leaving only the relevant information - it does this using a regex negative lookahead `(?!`..`)` to specify that if the current position matches the lookahead it should not be accepted as a match at this position.

(Also, it changes `to` to `-` and `°C to deg C` as per your expected values.)

```
<cfsavecontent variable="TempsRx">(?x)

    ## Exclude numbers, "deg", "C", "F", and GT sign.
    (?!
        \d+(?:[.,]\d+)?
    |
        \bdeg\b
    |
        \b[CF]\b
    |
        >
    )

    ## Match words
    \b[\w]+[\w-]*\b

</cfsavecontent>

<cfsavecontent trim variable="Inputs">
> 1000 °C ( > 1832 °F )
> -64,6 deg C (Ethylene glycol monobutyl ether acetate)
-30 to -15 deg C ( -22 to 5 deg F )
-64.5(Ethylene glycol monobutyl ether acetate)- -24.4 deg C(N-Methylpyrrolidone)
</cfsavecontent>

<cfloop index="CurIn" array=#Inputs.split('\n')# >

    <!---
        Replace 1/2: Normalise to/- and °/deg as per expected values
        Replace 3: Remove unwanted words
        Replace 4: Cleanup leftover parens
    --->
    <cfset Out = CurIn
        .replaceAll(' to ',' - ')
        .replaceAll('°(?=[CF]\b)','deg ')
        .replaceAll(TempsRx,'')
        .replaceAll('\(\s*\)',' ')
         />

    <cfdump var=#[CurIn,Out]# />

</cfloop>
```

Comment: Yay that works. And yes the first one would return two results because the groupings are either individual temperatures or temperature ranges.

But I can work with this!! Holy crap I hate regular expressions!!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you just want to remove anything that's inside parenthesis.

just remove anything that matches `\(.*?\)`

not that this will not work for nested parenthesis. If that is not an issue, than this approach should work fine :)