# extracting temperature degrees (celcius or fahrenheit) from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using `(char.*?char2)` in order to extract subparts which starts with `char1` and which ends with `char2` from a string.

Now I want to extract temperature information e.g. (40 °C, -30°C, 80°F) from a string. In this case my regex expression should define the beginning character with any digit characters by taking into the probability of `+` and `-`, and the ending with `°C` or `°F`, and there shouldn't be any letter in between, and it should also take `whitespace` character between the number and ending into possibility.

How can I define such a regex?

I have checked this, [Regex to extract temperatures and temperature ranges from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956793/regex-to-extract-temperatures-and-temperature-ranges-from-a-string), but the answer has slightly a different goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(\d+) ?°([CF])`

The first group should have the temperature, the second C or F.

Expanding it to allow for a bit more variation:

```
([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)*)\s?°([CcFf])
```

This would match [any of these](http://regexr.com/3fblp) inputs, allowing for more than one space, or tab, lower case unit, decimal points and signs.

Example python program:

```
import re
string = '''
20°C
2 °F
It was cold, 2 °F in fact.
30 °C
-40 °C
+2.3^I°c
+2.3°c
10°C
'''
pattern = r'([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)*)\s?°([CcFf])'
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
# Output:
# [('20', '', 'C'), ('2', '', 'F'), ('2', '', 'F'), ('30', '', 'C'),
# ('-40', '', 'C'), ('+2.3', '.3', 'c'), ('+2.3', '.3', 'c'),
# ('10', '', 'C')]
```

Comment: Andre, thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work for "30 °C".

Comment: It works for me. I tried in http://regexr.com/ Are you sure it's capital C? Or maybe there's a tab instead of a space. Or maybe I'm using a different `°` character than you?

Comment: Yes Andre, it is a capital C. And you are using the same ° character with mine. I am using python re.findall

Comment: http://regexr.com/3fblj Compare with this. If you are using python, make sure you enter the pattern in a raw string like `r'(\d+) ?°([CF])'` or `'''(\d+) ?°([CF])'''`, or escape backslashes like `(\\d+) ?°([CF])`.

Comment: Unfortunately Andre, any of the possibilities didn't work.

Comment: By the way, it would be cooler if the regular expression would cover + and - probability at the beginning.

Comment: I agree, but that wasn't part of the question. Updated now :)

Comment: Andre, I am really sorry, but it doesn't work with python. It works fine with regexr. :)

Comment: I have added a python program that I tried in both Python 2.7.1 and Python 3.6.0. Please ask a new question if you are still having problems!

Comment: yeah, it should be another case why it doesn't work in python.