# regular expression from regexr.com doesn't work in python

Tags: python, regex

I have such a function:

```
def get_temperature(s):
        parts = re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)*)\s?°([CcFf])', s)
        for a in range(len(parts)):
                s = s.replace(parts[a], "qTEMPq")
        return s
```

The input parameter `s` for the function is a string value. The output parameter is also a string value.

So at the end, if I have a string like `"It is +25°C outside."` as an input, the output string will be `"It is qTEMPq outside."`

The regular expression I am using from [extracting temperature degrees (celcius or fahrenheit) from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369010/extracting-temperature-degrees-celcius-or-fahrenheit-from-string) finds the subparts similar to (40°F, +30°C, -35 °C, etc.). It works perfectly in `regexr.com`, but not in my code.

What might be the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: did you installed the library `regexr`?

Comment: Hi! (again). What is the expected input and output of your function? When I try it with `get_temperature('30°C)` I get `TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not tuple`.

Comment: Input is string, and output is also string. I don't get any errors.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the exact code above? It will always throw an error as long as there's a match, since each match is a tuple.

Comment: Yes, I was also expecting a tuple, and for this reason an error. But no errors, nothing.

Comment: Could you add example strings and expected output, eg `'30°C' → 'qTEMPq°C'`

Comment: Your code will work for empty input strings, or strings that don't match eg `"foo"` - but crashes (for me) with `'30°C'` as input.

Comment: Please see [this page, about how to ask awesome questions](http://sscce.org/) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turned out to be an encoding (unicode) issue in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, by using "`\xb0`" instead of "`°`". It was an encoding issue. So basically, instead of using `'[+-]?\d+\.*\d*\s?°[CcFf]'` expression, I have used `'[+-]?\d+\.*\d*\s?\xb0[CcFf]'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 group (...) in your regex, findall will return a list of tuples.

If you want to obtain a list of strings, you can make the groups non-capturing using (?:...), as in:

```
import re
def get_temperature(s):
        parts = re.findall(r'(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s?°(?:[CcFf])', s)
        for a in range(len(parts)):
                s = s.replace(parts[a], "qTEMPq")
        return s
get_temperature('40.5°F')
# 'qTEMPq'
get_temperature('100°F is nearly 37°C')
# 'qTEMPq is nearly qTEMPq'
get_temperature("It is +25°C outside.")
# 'It is qTEMPq outside.'
```

If what you want is to access the parts of the temperature, you could do (in order to have tuples with value and unit):

```
def get_temperature(s):
        parts = re.findall(r'([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s?°([CcFf])', s)
        return parts

get_temperature("It is +25°C outside.")
#[('+25', 'C')]
```

Or, if you just want to have the whole temperature as a string:

```
def get_temperature(s):
        parts = re.findall(r'(?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)*)\s?°(?:[CcFf])', s)
        return parts
get_temperature('100°F is nearly 37°C')
# ['100°F', '37°C']
```

Comment: Thierry thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I basically don't get any match. The match list is empty.

Comment: The function returns exactly what you said you wanted in your example. Do you in fact want to obtain something else? The list of temperatures, as strings? Or tuples with the value and unit?

Comment: No, this function is basically a black box which gets the string as input, and masking temperatures with qTEMPq.

Comment: I know it should work, the reason I ask this question here is, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try to run the exact code from my answer? I ran it, and it gives the results you see. If it doesn't for you, what do you obtain? Error message, wrong output... ?

Comment: I obtain nothing. parts = []

Comment: Can you edit your question and state exactly what you expect: an example of input string, and the desired output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136260/discussion-between-thierry-lathuille-and-yusuf).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def get_temperature(s):
    return re.sub(r'[+-]?\d+\.*\d*\s?°[CcFf]', 'qTEMPq', s)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you rolika, but it doesn't work for me. I get 0 match.