# How can I find and replace a Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius with JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've been using the darksky API to practice API calls and JS in general, but I decided I would like to improve it to show both Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures by clicking on them. The API returns the temperature but also a summary about the temperature. To change the temperature part it was straight forward, but how do I even start on finding a Fahrenheit temperature in a sentence and changing only the temperature to Celsius?

Here is what the API returns as a summary (or an example of one as there are many different summaries).

No precipitation throughout the week, with high temperatures peaking at 56°F on Thursday.

I can change the 56°F when I only get the temperature returned, but I can't figure out how to change it when it is part of the sentence.

Any help would be extremely appreciated, even more so if you could add a small explanation to your answer to ensure I learn instead of just copy pasting.

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369010/extracting-temperature-degrees-celcius-or-fahrenheit-from-string) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) would be good jumping off points.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander! With that I was able to solve the problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander pointing me in the right direction, I managed to do it like this:

```
celsiusCalc = Math.floor((summary.search(/(\d+) ?°/) - 32) * (5 / 9));
celsiusSummary = summary.replace(/(\d+) ?°[F]/, celsiusCalc + "°C");
temperatureDescription.textContent = celsiusSummary;
```

To apply this to your problem, change out summary for the string you want to change the temperature in, and change the temperatureDescription to the div in which you would like to put the new, Celsius valued, text into.